# Strange behavior in jQuery top vs. bottom position

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

I'm seeing a strange difference between top and bottom positioning.
I've put together four quick examples to demonstrate the issue:

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/8kpe8/)**

```
//example 1
$('#box1').hover(function () {
    var offset = $('#box1').offset();
    $("#containment-wrapper1").css({
        bottom: offset.top
    });
});

//example 2
$('#box2').hover(function () {
    var x = $('#box2').css('top');
    $("#containment-wrapper2").css({
        bottom: x
    });
});

//example 3
$('#box3').hover(function () {
    var x = $('#box3').css('top');
    $("#containment-wrapper3").css({
        top: x
    });
});

//example 4
$('#box4').hover(function () {
    var offset = $('#box4').offset();
    $("#containment-wrapper4").css({
        top: offset.top
    });
});
```

Examples 3 and 4, behave as expected, the top border lines up with the bottom border.

Examples 1 and 2 do not. There seems to be about a 30px difference.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bug and no strange behaviour.

You've set all of your containers to `position: fixed`. Therefore their positioning is relative to the window.

So while the distance from the top will never change, the distance from the bottom will vary based on screen size. If you resize the window you will see the position changes and at some point the box will line up.

The fact you are measuring the distance from the top and then applying it to the bottom makes it even more likely this will fail as the screen would have to be exactly the right size.

Basically, you are asking:
If the box is, say, 100px from the top, then why when I make the containment-wrapper 100px from the bottom don't they line up?

Comment: I think I get it now, thanks for taking the time to spell it out for me.